# Which actions bumps up old question to the first pages?

Tags: discussion, questions, bump, top-questions

I meant following pages when I say "first pages"

All questions - https://stackoverflow.com/questions

Top questions - https://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: @gnat: You just bumped this question by tagging it with a bump tag. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any of the following:

- Edit on the question.
- Edit on any of the answers.
- Close (I think)
- Reopen
- Random **[poking by Community](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community)**

Comments do *not* bump a question to the top.

Answer (score 2):

Any edit on the question or answer will bump it to the top. Also there are some random questions which might be selected by the system to appear on the top if there hasn't been any activity on them for a long period of time. I have seen many people abusing this though, like adding a space or something insignificant to their question in order to make it appear on the top and attract more attention. Remember that if the question is bad, what it will attract is downvotes instead of answers.

Comment: I got to watch someone bump his question right into CW status the other day. Karma!